# Companding and uniform quantizaton in Matlab

Tags: matlab, uniform, quantization

I hava a function for quantization and decrease the bit depth of images and then increase it and compare with original image.As result I need a table like this:(MSE:mean square error)

[image]

but I don't know a much about companding and uniform qauntizations.
this is my function.

```
function [Q,Q2,Err] = quantization (I,b);
img=imread(I);
Q=uint8(img/2^(8-b));
Q2=uint8(Q*2^(8-b));
Err=mean(mean((double(img) - double(Q2)).^2,2),1);
subplot(1,4,1), imshow(img)
subplot(1,4,2), imshow(Q)
subplot(1,4,3), imshow(Q2)
display(Err)
end
```

help me please...

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: I must fill that table.so I wanna change the function to get MSE of two images after companding and uniform quantizations.